# text launcher in gnome classic

Tags: gnome, launcher

How do I create a text based launcher in gnome classic? I want to be able to keyboard shortcut and have a list of apps come up as I type just like gnome 3, unity and windows 7 has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synapse may be exactly what you want. Suits me fine https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/

Comment: That one's nice too. And in the regular repo! The one hole in Stack is when there are two equally correct answers... +1

Comment: On further review, Synapse wins for tracking activities and documents as well.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary Slingshot seems to be working nicely. It's kinda like Launchpad in OSX